# How to use bash tee to redirect stdout and stderr to a file from script which has screen in the hash bang

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, tee

I have a script which needs to run in screen so I included

```
#!/usr/bin/screen /bin/bash
```

as the hash bang and it works great. The only problem is that when the script crashes I don't know what happened, the output is lost and all I know is that screen terminated.

My script is interactive so I need to see stdout and stderr in the terminal and I also want stdout and stderr logged in case it crashed.

I tried to run the script like

```
./test-screen-in-bash.sh 2>&1|tee test1.log
```

which results in an empty test1.log file

Can somebody please explain what am I doing wrong.

Comment: It creates a new terminal, your `2>&1` is for the current terminal and therefore is not connected to the new one and recieves none of it's data. One way to log the data is to use the -L flag with the screen command.

Comment: Thanks @JID, It work great on it's own but not sure how to include this in the hash bang, I tried `#!/usr/bin/screen -L /bin/bash` but it says L is an unknown option tough I have -L in there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't, is there a reason it needs to be the shebang ? If you want to run it inside screen you can do something similar to the top answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162133/run-script-in-a-screen). It will allow you to pass all the flags you want :)

Comment: Thanks again @JID. The link you provided was what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JID comments I was able to find what i was looking for.

I removed the screen from hash bang and used the method from the link provided by @JID [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162133/run-script-in-a-screen) in the first answer.

I ended up with

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then exec screen -L /bin/bash "$0"; fi
./myscript.sh
```

Now when I run the above, myscript.sh runs in screen and the whole output from the session is dumped to screenlog.n files.